# event log of an application

Tags: visual-c++

how to access the event log of an application using visual c++ API .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS has a collection of functions to access the various event logs. 
You can find their documentation here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363654(VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for the link , I am going through it ( seems to be useful ).